# I attempted a dual boot installation of Ubuntu on separate SSDs, but Windows 10 is missing from the grub menu options. How can I fix this?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows

I have an SSD which has the windows 10 OS installed on it and a SATA M.2 which has Ubuntu installed. I checked the files (while running Ubuntu) and the Windows 10 SSD and its contents are still there.

I also have two HDDs, one I used for Windows storage and one I planned to leave for Ubuntu storage.

The grub menu lists options for Ubuntu, 2 Windows boot managers (which are from my HDDs) and system setup which takes me to the BIOS. Those two boot managers don't really do anything (I think?) since I keep those drives exclusively for games, media etc.

What boggled my mind even more was - if I just tried to boot up my PC with only the Windows 10 SSD and its corresponding HDD storage hooked up, I would get a message saying "attempting to repair" along those lines and windows 10 won't even boot up...

I attempted `sudo update-grub` and these were my logs:

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-22-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-22-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-20-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-20-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sdc1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sdd2@/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
```

So it found the Boot manger from my hard drives...but nothing from the SSD. What should I do now?

Comment: To format terminal output, don't use quoting formatting with double spacing. Instead, select it with the mouse and press the `{}` button in the editor.

Comment: Need output for `lsblk -o name,partlabel,UUID,fstype,mountpoint`

Answer (score 0):

This might work and there's no risk in trying:

Begin powered down. 
<---- that's important

Plug in or make bootable so that both OS are available from power on, such as plugging in that Ubuntu HDD with the Windows 10 already on internal HDD. or two HDDs or two partitions - you get the idea.

Only then power up and get into the to BIOS
--> BIOS boot tab---> disable secure boot ---->look for the Ubuntu drive in listed drives -----> should see both OS in the list ---> bring Ubuntu top of list<-.... save and exit. Reboot and pray to the RNG. If it worked the grub boot manager should start and both OS be list if the medium that stores it is plugged in or however you choose to structure it before booting. 
It will either work or do nothing. Either way the outcome is not detrimental.

It's basic , but worked for me with live boot flash drive and HDD dual OS booting. Best to try the simple methods first before diving into lines of code.